# signal name `somename' is invalid for instance `0x80c00b0'

Tags: c, gtk, signals, glib

I am trying to register a new signal on a GtkWidget ( GooCanvas) following the inst.  [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/signal.html#signal-registration) I did:

```
g_signal_new                         ("canvas_changed",
                                     G_TYPE_FROM_INSTANCE(canvas),
                                     G_SIGNAL_RUN_LAST | G_SIGNAL_ACTION,
                                     0,
                                     NULL, NULL,
                                     g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__POINTER,
                                     G_TYPE_NONE,
                                     1,
                                     G_TYPE_POINTER);
```

But when I try to emit the signal on the canvas:

```
g_signal_emit_by_name(canvas, "changed2");
```

I get the error:

```
signal name `changed2' is invalid for instance `0x80c00b0'
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? I tried passing some other types but still not result? Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with this ?

```
g_signal_emit_by_name(canvas, "canvas_changed");
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, we all have sometime made an overlooked :-)